# Select single next sibling using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I am using jquery draggable to add the content to td of my editor. Whenever I am doing this, I am adding an extra tr just next to the parent tr(using `insertAfter`) of TD on which content are dropped. Added tr has one TD in it with text `this is a copy of tr`. Now the problem is tr gets added every time user drops the content.this happens when he tries to replace the already dropped content too. which result in the addition of unnecessary tr.

How can I ensure that tr only gets added once next to parent tr of dropped td??

```
    var objTR = $(TableEditor.sourceTD).parent(); /*Get the source TD's parent row */
    var clone = $(objTR).clone(); /*Clone the entire Row in the memory and then insert it */
    if (!copyContent) $(clone).find('td').html("Change the content of this column"); /* if copyContent is false then loop through all the TD's and empty the content of the Td */
    $(clone).find('td').remove();
    $(clone).html('<td class="unlocked" replacesource="1" height="200" valign="top">This is a copy of TR </tr>')
    $(clone).insertAfter(objTR); /*insert the new row*/
```

Comment: can you provide us some code or a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method.

```
$('sometagid').next();
```